# Object of type 'CombinedExpression' is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, ajax, django

I've set a like/dislike function for comments in my app but when user clicks on like or dislike for the first time it gives me error which I noted in the title. but this happens just in the first time and if user clicks on like or dislike again it works completely fine.

what is "CombinedExpression" anyway?

my views.py:

```
@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
def like(request, comment_id):
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comments, pk=comment_id)
    if request.POST:
        # handling like or dislike
    if request.is_ajax():
        return JsonResponse({'cmplus':comment.cmpvote, 'cmminus':comment.cmmvote})

    return HttpResponseRedirect(my reverse return)
```

for the record I have to say cmpvote and cmmvote are the number of like and dislikes of a comment and are integers with default of 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What happens in `if request.POST` part? Is there anything that happens only on the first click?

`CombinedExpression` is a result of Django's `F` function. So if you do something like

```
comment.cmpvote = F('cmpvote') + 1
```

the value of `comment.cmpvote` will be

```
<CombinedExpression: F(cmpvote) + Value(1)>
```

and not the actual number of votes.

To solve this, call `comment.refresh_from_db()` before serializing the object.

Comment: the problem was the F function. I should've use "update" function when saving my new data or your suggestion. thanks.

Comment: Please explain this solution better,i have a similar issue ```account_metric.data["request_count"] = F("data__request_count") + 1```